# Why is the usual definition of equivalence of categories sufficiently restrictive?

Tags: category-theory

Given categories $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$, an equivalence from $\mathbf{C}$ to $\mathbf{D}$ is a pair of functors $F : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ and $G : \mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ together with natural isomorphisms $$\eta : FG \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_\mathbf{C} : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$$ $$\varepsilon : \mathrm{id}_\mathbf{D} \rightarrow GF: \mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$$

Honestly, I don't understand why these conditions are sufficient. Shouldn't we add some further requirements, like the assumption that $$\eta F \star F \varepsilon = \mathrm{id}_\mathrm{F} : F \rightarrow F : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$$

for example?

(I've been away from math for awhile and can't remember standard category theory notation, but hopefully the meaning of the expression $\eta F \star F \varepsilon$ is fairly clear. Please comment if you're unsure of what I'm asking.)

Comment: An equivalent definition of an equivalence is a functor which is full, faithful, and essentially surjective, which means (for most people) the categories are pretty much the same. Are there any extra properties you would want out of an equivalence?

Comment: @Joppy Well, it's a weaker condition than *isomorphism* of categories.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, note that whereas isomorphism of categories violates the principle that we shouldn't talk about equality of objects (equivalently functors), the condition discussed in my question does not. In particular, it only talks about equality of natural transformations (equivalently, arrows), which is fair game.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [adjoint equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence) which is certainly a nicer thing. We can [get an adjoint equivalence from an equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence#theorem).

Comment: @DerekElkins, interesting. So maybe adjoint equivalence is really the correct notion, and "ordinary" equivalence just happens to be good enough due to the construction you just linked.

Comment: @DerekElkins, you should expand your comment into an answer.

Comment: Ideally we really do want adjoint equivalences, I think.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Can you explain what an adjoint equivalence does that a usual equivalence does not? Requiring an adjunction seems fairly natural.